# Novel Interaction Techniques

Tags: user-interface, graphics, interaction, human-computer-interface

What exactly are Novel Interaction Techniques, in the context of Human Computer Interaction and Computer Graphics? I have some confusion in mind regarding this, can someone explain with examples? Thanks.

Comment: "Novel" is just a fancy word for "new".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Novel" is a synonym for "new".  So, a "novel interaction technique" is any mechanism for human-computer interaction which is different or groundbreaking.  What is novel today may be run-of-the-mill tomorrow.  In the past, using "windows" and "folders" were novel ideas.  Today they are the norm.